# Django - How to trigger an action when a specific model is saved?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. One called MainModel and other called HistoricMainModel. I would like to INSERT automatically a row in the HistoricMainModel every time I data is inserted to MainModel. What is best/correct way of doing this in Django?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 10):

If you already have some custom `save()`.-magic going on I would recommend using a `post_save()` signal or a `pre_save()` which ever would work best for you.

in your `models.py`

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MainModel)
def save_a_historicmodel(sender, **kwargs):
    #do your save historicmodel logic here
```

or

```
def save_a_historicmodel(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "Post save was triggered! Instance:", instance

signals.post_save.connect(save_a_historicmodel, sender=MainModel)
```

This works so that every time your `MainModel` is saved this signal is triggered.

[Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite `save` method in MainModel model to create and insert the HistoricMainModel object before calling the "real" `save` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this yourself but the *best* way would be to use an application that does this - like [`reversion`](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/) - a django app that implements model history/roll back automatically.

In addition to whatever you will implement, `reversion` will provide you with:

1. Integration with the [admin backend](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Admin-integration).
2. A [API](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Low-level-API) to add meta-data to your versions and to revert back to previous versions of your model.

It is a lot more flexible and is widely used and implemented.